# How to reduce 20 V to 3.6 V to power flashlights

Tags: power-supply, voltage, converter

I am planning on using a DeWalt 20 V battery pack to power two Thrunite TH30 flashlights. They need **3.6 volts** and **5.18 amps** for both of them combined.

The flashlights will be physically connected, but with separate power buttons. I will be using the DeWalt battery pack to power the lights exclusively, they will not be using their own batteries. In theory, I could just solder the wires to the battery contacts in the lights and they would work like that.

Is there a way that I could reduce the voltage while extending the length of runtime?

-The LEDs are Cree XHP70.2 which have a maximum drive current: 4800 mA (6 V), 2400 mA (12 V)
-The batteries are 3100mAh IMR 18650 3.6 V

I am open to any advice or refinements to the idea that you may have.

*Here is the list of parts I have.*

[Buck Converter](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/TDK-Lambda/I3A4W008A033V-001-R?qs=5aG0NVq1C4yZL4vqe7IdfA%3D%3D)
[3 Amp Fuse](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Bourns/SF-1206F300M-2?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsIz3CjQ1xegZx2pdJYlypr7Ds7LUjoOvkYoyz7lxPnnQ%3D%3D)
[13 kOhms Resister](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/KOA-Speer/CF1-4C133J?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsPqMdJzcrNwlO14QoJqV9wzmpmUrRkYfc%3D)
[220 uF Capacitor](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/KEMET/A759KR227M1VAAE024?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvR1wrj203KOIBOOW3024qOL2SacNxUk0MZuXKiClmnCQ%3D%3D)
[10 uF Capacitor](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Taiyo-Yuden/GMK316AB7106KL-TR?qs=I6KAKw0tg2zjwfBQFDR86Q%3D%3D)
[220 uF Capacitor](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Nichicon/RR70J221MDN1?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvR1wrj203KOCqOaCjKxmF5W8LXXcgKszA%3D)

[TL431](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/TL431BCLP?qs=odmYgEirbwxQXewQAocCsg%3D%3D)
[2N3906](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/onsemi-Fairchild/2N3906TF?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtqBmg8fZQA6%252BaeWKFDvvf1)
[2N3904](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/onsemi-Fairchild/2N3904TF?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsVgcksf1EMUgdIs9AeVM0%252B)
[330 ohms](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/KOA-Speer/CF1-2C331J?qs=xbcAFrEQFKFGgbTgjb6pXA%3D%3D)
[51K Ohms](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/YAGEO/CFR-25JB-52-51K?qs=oypCK0zG325x%252BvjFp7qkVA%3D%3D)
[10K Ohms](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-Holsworthy/CFR200J10K?qs=DDevMFOh4svCnes960laCw%3D%3D)
[22K Ohms](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-Holsworthy/CFR100J22K?qs=DDevMFOh4suDQzQSKcUHqA%3D%3D)

I built the PCB twice, and both times there was a short. The caps are not the problem, and there are no shorts in the actual circuit board. When I solder the buck converter to the rest of the circuit, it then shorts.

[image: PCB]

*Above* Here is the circuit diagram. Copper is Orange, The caps and resistor are green. The white dots are the contacts for the converter.

[image: Blank PCB]

*Above* Here is the blank PCB. There are no shorts.

[image: PCB with 10 uF Caps]

*Above* Here are the 10 uF caps on the board, again no shorts.
[image: Burnt Converter]

*Above* Here is the converter, It shorted when I added it on above the 10 uF caps and applied power. It melted the  black chip on the right.

I think there was a short somewhere in the converter. Maybe I melted something accidently when I was soldering to the leads? I'm assuming that I need to buy another converter. I think the rest of the circuit is sound, so I'll rebuild the circuit when I get the replacement converter.

Comment: A DCDC charger converter is need to regulate the output to both loads wired in parallel with suitable current and voltage limits

Comment: Do the flashlights have batteries? Are you going to leave the flashlight batteries in place or get rid of them and use the dewalt battery (with appropriate step-down circuit) as your power source? Tony Stewart is saying you need a charger because he is assuming you are going to keep the batteries in the lights. And I agree with him. UNLESS you are removing the batteries. Then you just need a buck converter to supply around 4 V to the lights.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75    The lights have built-in charging ports and Dewalt sells an adapter for their batteries that lets you use two USB cables to charge your phone, etc. But I will not be using the flashlight batteries, so I will need something different. Thanks for your help though, I appreciate it!

Comment: How much current do the flashlights draw from 3.6V? You say the LEDs can take 6V 4.8A which is ridiculously high, this would require a special lithium battery like IMR. But do the flashlight's internal electronics actually deliver all that current? Perhaps it is lower. You must know the current to choose a suitable DC-DC converter.

Comment: Draw a block diagram with impedance or V,A of each interface and choose the simplest path.

Comment: @bobflux   I am not sure what current the flashlights draw. I researched the LEDs in them and the maximum drive current is what I found in the company's stats for it. Would you know of a way that I could measure the current to find out what it is? 

I'm sorry, I should be more specific. The battery is a LiR IMR18650 3100 MAH 3.6v 11.16Wh High discharge performance Li-ion Rechargeable Battery.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75,  
I can try to figure out how to draw a block diagram, But I don't know where to start.
What would be the benefit of making one?

Again, I have not done anything electrical like this before, I'm a noob. I'm sorry if this is frustrating for you guys.

Comment: OK, IMR battery, makes sense, can deliver very high current, also used in power tools batteries. Other types of LiIon have higher capacity but lower current, often used in laptops. Since this project involves connecting wires to battery contacts in flashlight, this would be a good opportunity to wire it and measure current with a multimeter on 10A range. Use freshly charged battery, to compensate for voltage drop across multimeter.

Comment: Do you want to use this flashlight because you like the beam? Another option would be to keep your flashlight, then buy LEDs and optics and build a light from them to use with your dewalt battery.

Comment: No need for a two step approach. One buck converter should solve all you needs.

Comment: @winny, Hi, so how would one converter work? If I set it to 3.6v, would both lights get 3.6v? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, unless there is something hidden in the details. Please draw a block diagram of what you have and how you plan to connect it.

Comment: @bobflux I am planning on using the flashlights because I have used them before and they perform great. I am not picky about the beam, but buying 2 for this makes sense for me because I can still adjust the brightness, and I would get the two batteries from them for other uses. It would cost about $160 cad for me to buy them, which is not cheap, but I'm not sure how that would compare to buying parts. Also, they are already assembled and compact, so it is easier overall in my opinion to get them.

Comment: Please don't buy the LM2596 modules. They're all counterfeit and they will fail. You can google "counterfeit lm2596" for examples.

Comment: Your block diagram is sound. You should be good to go.

Comment: Are those decoupling capacitors? Off board? What threshold voltage does the enable pin require and what do you measure on it?

Comment: @winny I measured the voltage going into the converter On/Off switch by using a multimeter with the red lead on the positive terminal and the black lead on the switch terminal. It gave a reading of 13 volts. I removed the entire circuit LEADING INTO the converter and connected the battery straight to the terminals, and also connected the On/Off terminal directly to the ground wire, I measured the voltage in the same manner as above and got 20 volts. The converter only turned on with the 20 volts leading into it and not the 13 volts. Should I measure it differently?

Comment: Does that answer your questions?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot, yes I also think they are decoupling capacitors.

Comment: I really like your prototype technique. You should search on "cordwood module" for ideas to get you from 2 to 3 dimensions.

Comment: @stretch Thanks, I don't know if I'd call it a technique though! I have never heard of cordwood modules before, but they seem like an excellent idea, I could probably turn the  Undervoltage circuit into one, that should make it a lot tighter. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

With such high difference of input and output and the requirement for efficiency (long run times on battery), you should prefer switching regulator rathr than linear.

The type of regulator you need depends on the output current that you need.

If the consumption of your flashlights is less than 3 amps, google "LM2596", you will find some modules (small boards) with this type of regulator. Output voltage can be set using a trimmer (typycaly a blue box with screw-head on top).

For better reliability, the trimmer can be desoldered and replaced by constant resistors (there is usually SMD pad under the trimmer), but that is not necessary.

Comment: By reliability, are you referring to accidentally changing the trimmer? A dab of hot glue on the screw can also take care of that if the soldering is too finicky.

Comment: I think the trimmer can also be affected by humidity and probably somewhat aging. But the change of output won't be significant for flashlight.

Comment: Ah yes good point. It may not matter here, but it's always good to remove unneeded complexities that are potential points of failure.

Comment: @Passerby The LM2596 seems like a good idea, except I need around 5.16 Amps for the lights. Thanks for your help though.  I forgot to answer you sooner.  I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a nice ready-made DC-DC ([link](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/TDK-Lambda/I3A4W008A033V-001-R?qs=5aG0NVq1C4yZL4vqe7IdfA%3D%3D)) that will suit your needs. It has a maximum current of 9A so you only need one. You can adjust output voltage with a resistor (read datasheet). You can use a 50k potentiometer to adjust, then replace with a fixed resistor of the appropriate value once it is set. This is to avoid the failure mode of the pot wiper disconnecting with age.

The flashlights should be wired in parallel.

Here's a [link](https://www.mouser.fr/c/power/dc-dc-converters/non-isolated-dc-dc-converters/?input%20voltage%2C%20max=24%20V%7E%7E60%20VDC&number%20of%20outputs=1%20Output&output%20voltage-channel%201=0.6%20V%20to%2012%20V%7E%7E0.7525%20V%20to%205.5%20V%7C%7E3%20V%20to%206%20V%7C%7E3.3%20V%20to%2015%20V%7E%7E3.3%20V%20to%2040%20V&instock=y&rp=power%2Fdc-dc-converters%2Fnon-isolated-dc-dc-converters%7C%7EInput%20Voltage%2C%20Max%7C%7EOutput%20Voltage-Channel%201&sort=pricing) to the mouser search if you're interested in other models.

Please do not buy the fake LM2596 modules. They're all counterfeit, they will die, and they will destroy the flashlights.

Since the flashlight runs on one lithium battery, you can be sure its maximum input voltage is at least equal to the voltage on a fully charged cell. So I'd suggest setting the DC-DC to 4.2V instead of 3.6V. This will increase efficiency of the flashlight LED driver.

You also need to know if the battery has undervoltage protection. Some power tools brands put that feature in the battery, but some others implement it in the tool. In the later case, your project could over-discharge the battery, which greatly shortens its life. So if the battery does not have undervoltage protection, a TL431 controlling the DC-DC's ENABLE input will do the job.

Note the flashlight's undervoltage protection is not relevant here, because it monitors the output voltage of the DC-DC converter, not the output voltage of your 20V battery.

According to the [specs](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/power/switching-power/dc-dc-converter/specification/i3a_spec.pdf) the trim resistor should be 13 kOhms for 4.2V output. So you don't need a pot, just a resistor, unless my calculation is wrong of course.

[image]

You should wire the lights in parallel (as drawn). Not in series!

Capacitors circled in green are **not optional**, and both should have very low ESR. The schematic above gives bare minimum values, but the eval board recommends a lot more, so that's what I'd use...

Considering the high currents, you need proper wiring and grounding. Personally I would either make a PCB, or use a piece of blank copperclad PCB to mount the module on. With a bit of milling with a dremel you can make some big fat copper traces like that, which give low resistance and low inductance, which are both important here.

[image]

Copper in blue, capacitors in orange.

Here's the [link](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/power/switching-power/pwr-acc/instruction_manual/i3axxa_i6axxa-c01-evk-s1_apl.pdf) to the eval board schematics. If you want to do the same, they put 3x10µF X7R 63V ceramics on the input and 5x10µF ceramics on the output, and one polymer cap on both sides.

You can use other caps, no need for 63V since you'll only be using 20V on the input and 4.2V on the input. As usual with ceramics, it's cheaper to get 10 of the same value rather than 3 of one value and 5 of another, so just search for [10µF 35V X7R](https://www.mouser.fr/c/passive-components/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors/mlccs-multilayer-ceramic-capacitors/multilayer-ceramic-capacitors-mlcc-smd-smt/?capacitance=10%20uF&dielectric=X7R&voltage%20rating%20dc=35%20VDC&instock=y&sort=pricing), pick the cheapest ones in qty 10, buy 10, and just put 5 on the input and 5 on the output.

Suggestions for [input polymer cap](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/KEMET/A759KR227M1VAAE024?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvR1wrj203KOIBOOW3024qOL2SacNxUk0MZuXKiClmnCQ%3D%3D) and [output polymer cap](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Nichicon/RR70J221MDN1?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvR1wrj203KOCqOaCjKxmF5W8LXXcgKszA%3D).

If you use a 6V3 cap on the output, do not solder it before adjusting the output voltage!

Given the current, you have to use polymer caps, not normal cheap caps. The latter can't handle the ripple current, they'll just overheat and pop like the ones on the fake LM2596 modules. And don't get leaded ceramic caps, they have to be SMD for low inductance.

Here's an undervoltage protection circuit using TL431. When voltage on this chip's REF pin rises above 2.5V, it will draw enough current to turn on both transistors and set ON/OFF pin to 0V, which turns on the switching converter. Voltage can be adjusted by changing the 51k resistor. You can use any cheap small signal transistors, 3904/3906, BC547/557, etc.

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank you for finding that. I will use it instead of the LM2596's. 
I believe most DeWalt power tools have Undervoltage protection built in them. My flashlights blink once the battery is (empty), so I think I'm good in that aspect.
4.2 V would work great, as the battery gives that voltage at the start of its output.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am finding it tough to grasp, how do the voltage (and amps) change with the second light being used in parallel? Do I need to double the power, or does twice the amount of power flow through at the regular current? If twice the voltage is going through the wires, there would be too much power if only one light was turned on.

Comment: Wire the lights in parallel: each light's "+" terminal to the DC-DC's "output +", and each light's "-" terminal to the DC-DC's Ground, they will both receive the same voltage (ie, 4.2V). Each will draw the current it needs. So the total current out of the switching converter is the sum of both flashlights' currents. Do not wire them in series, that won't work.

Comment: I edited the answer to add more details.

Comment: Thank you for drawing that, It is very helpful. I reedited the question, maybe you could check that some time for me. :)  In your diagram, two of the capacitors have a symbol approx. like a Roman Numeral 3 with a plus sign after it. Could you tell me what it means? I looked online, and couldn't find it. Thanks

Comment: So the capacitors above, your first diagram shows 3, and your next diagram shows 10. You are suggesting that I add five caps in parallel before and after the buck converter. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes correct, at this high current it'll need several caps in parallel. I just looked at what they put on the evaluation board for this DC-DC. The hatched "roman numeral" capacitor symbol means electrolytic. It would be much safer to keep the battery whole with its protection PCB though, instead of extracting the cells. Also if you keep it whole, you can use the original charger.

Comment: Ok, so I am putting together a list of what I need in the original post. So If I get 5 of your suggested input caps and 5 of your output caps, that should be the last thing I need? Also, is there anything I need to get for the undercharge protector besides the TL41?   I am planning to put the battery on my belt, and use a cord running up my back to the light on my head/helmet, so yes, I am planning on keeping the battery pack as it is. We have lots of them, so I will be able to run the light continually.

Comment: The 2x5 caps are the ceramic ones, for the polymer caps you only need 1 per side.  I put a TL431 schematic in the answer.

Comment: Thank you once again. :) Sadly, I have realized that I am going in deeper and deeper over my head. Do I dare ask? What is the possibility that I could fund the project and you could build it? I am referring to the converter and the undercharge protection. -mark

Comment: Ha, unfortunately my plate is full!

Comment: No problem, I shall persevere, I have a smart friend that can probably help me. Thanks though! :D

Comment: I believe I have everything I need to build the circuits. Before I order the parts could you please go over what I have and see if it is correct? Thank you. :)

Comment: Looks good. If you use "sort by price" on TL431 you'll save a buck ;)

Comment: Probably won't break the bank, but I changed it. Thank you. :) So should I now press   "Answer Your Question"? Or should I wait till the project is built and I verify that it works?

Comment: As you wish! You can wait

Comment: I shall wait then. :)

Comment: Hi, I built the undervoltage protector. Do you mind checking if it is built correctly before I make it more compact? Thank you for your time! mark

Comment: Looks good, if you have a bench power supply with variable voltage you can test it.

Comment: I don't have a bench power supply. I guess I'll just wait till the other circuit is built before testing it then. How do I connect this to the other circuit? Does the (V1) in the diagram connect to the negative and the (on/off)  goes directly into the on/off terminal on the buck converter? Are there other connections I'm not seeing? Thank you once again.

Comment: V1 is the battery. Its "-" is also the ground for everything else. The on/off terminal should connect to the "on/off" input on the DC-DC module. I rechecked the datasheet, and I don't see any maximum voltage for the on/off input pin. So I think it would be better to remove the LED and R7 from the schematic, just in case.

Comment: "it doesnt work" doesn't mean much. Do you have voltage on the output? Which voltage? Try removing the undervoltage protection and shunting the ON/OFF pin to GND  to make sure the DC-DC is enabled. Also with the flimsy wiring, capacitors will have high inductance, so you shouldn't expect it to deliver high output current. The caps really need to be mounted on a PCB with very wide copper like in my drawing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote my previous comment very poorly. After working on the project more I have found that the buck converter works fine. I am using it with just the capacitors that come after it, connected to the 2 flashlights. The converter outputs about 4.27 volts, which is good. I can order a copper-clad PCB if you think it is necessary, I trust your judgment, but the 5 caps in a row seem to be working fine on the latter half of the circuit.  Does the Undervoltage circuit need to be mounted on a pcb too? Somehow I need to figure out how to make that work.

Comment: OK! so it works, excellent. It doesn't absolutely need a PCB, but making a PCB would definitely be a plus, not just for electrical stuff. If you want this to be portable it has to hold together and just work reliably, and a pcb is quite good for this. Think about the enclosure you will use, how you will mount it, where screw holes need to be, the wires, the switch, etc.

Comment: It does work great, but I think the Undervoltage circuit might need to be changed. I have updated the question above. The battery will be on my hip with wires leading to the light on my forehead. The flashlights fit on each end of a PVC pipe. The piece of PVC pipe is 1" wide by 2" long. I will be placing all the circuits in the pipe adjacent to the lights providing they fit. I don't think I will need a switch, I have an adapter plug that I will add, so I can disconnect that or the battery. A PCB does seem like a good idea. Could I use a Perfboard to obtain the same results? Thanks

Comment: You can use perfboard for the voltage circuit. For the high current buck the traces will be too thin. If you want to DIY, you can use a bit of blank copper clad PCB and check the drawing I made in the answer, just make a few cuts with dremel or blade.

Comment: Thank you, I will get some copper-clad PCB then. Is there something that you can recommend that I try to get the Undervoltage circuit to work properly? It only supplies about 13 V to the On/Off switch, but the switch needs 20 V. I have elaborated above. At the same time, I would prefer if it could be cut out at about 16.5 V. In your first diagram about the Undervoltage circuit, you mentioned that the voltage could be adjusted by changing the 51K resistor. Do you mean the voltage cut-off point, or the voltage going into the On/Off terminal?

Comment: Hello, I have built the circuit on a copper-clad PCB and updated the question. Because of the size of the project, the copper traces are only about 3/16 wide in some areas. Is that too small, or should I cut another board? There are some issues with the caps also that I wrote about above. Do you mind if you could check what I am doing wrong this time? (when you have the time)  Thank you once again.

Comment: If the wires overheat you have a short, can you post a picture?

Comment: I have posted a picture. I also checked the PCB board, but I don't think it has any shorts in it. If you need more pictures, I can get them.

Comment: I was not sure where the shorts were, so I remade the circuit board. As I soldered components on, I connected it to power each time to check for shorts. There were none till I added the converter. Consequently, I think I melted a component on the converter, and I think I need to order another one. Are there any other parts that I should get when I order it?

Comment: I have rebuilt the undervoltage circuit. In one of your previous comments, you said to remove the led and R7 from it. Am I supposed to replace them with a wire, or just remove the connection altogether? Also, the connection is made when the power is above 2.5 volts. I need it to connect when it's above 16.5 volts.  Is there a resistor that I should use instead of the 51k one? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm very sorry this is taking so long. I should have figured this out a lot quicker, but I haven't. Do you mind answering my last question? I realized what I did wrong building the undervoltage circuit, and I think it will work fine now. I just need to know what resister I should use instead of the 51K one. I need the ref pin to turn on the other transistors at 16 - 16.5 V instead of 2.5 V.  Thank you for the time you have spent helping me work on this. There is no way I could have got to this point without help.

Answer (score 3):

A basic step down switching regulator will work of you don't want to mess with whatever circuit is builtin to the flashlights. At 80 to 95% efficiency it's your best bet.

Not noting the current needs, you probably want to measure the amperage with the existing batteries before you replace them. Then you can find a suitable regulator meeting both the current and voltage requirements.

You will put them both in parallel. You do not want to put them in series.

Comment: How would I measure the amperage from the batteries, and is there a way to figure out what amperage is being used by the lights?  Thanks.

Comment: @MarkH. Multimeter.

Comment: @mark an ammeter or a multimeter in current mode in-between the battery and the flashlight. You probably want to make sure you are in the 10A range.

Comment: @MarkH. Based on your edits nothing really changes. No the switch regulator won't produce any really visible flucations in the lights. If the flashlight has any internal boost led driver then it will smooth it out even more. And either use 2 switching regulators (one each due to current needed) or one high average switching regulator to power both. A resistor is not good for this. 3.6V @ 3 Amps is 9 watts of wasted power so you would need beefy 10 Watt power resistors. And it would mean half the battery capacity/run time.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks for the edits. :) Based on the size of the regulators, I can fit two easily in my project. I believe these will work fine. Right?  Also, reading a comment about the regulators, if they fail, the flashlights will cook so I plan to add a 4.5 V resistor (approximately) between the converter and the light as a backup in case the converter fails.  I will let you guys know how it turns out. Cheers, Mark

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/Zixtec-Converter-Voltage-Regulator-3-0-40V/dp/B07VVXF7YX/ref=sr_1_5?gclid=Cj0KCQiAu62QBhC7ARIsALXijXStLgYl9TpxaBqN8u00RPT8oPTKS_sMTzntgmtsq52b7nb2yrFYclgaAsa5EALw_wcB&hvadid=326964555511&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9001480&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=e&hvrand=14071195649395407441&hvtargid=kwd-313814655507&hydadcr=19938_10102479&keywords=lm2596+dc+to+dc+buck+converter&qid=1644982923&sr=8-5

Comment: @MarkH. Again the issue with that is the wasted power which is heat. You'll need a way to cool 10 watts of power. You may be better off using a fuse as protection instead. Or you can ask a new question about how to protect your leds from overcurrent/voltage in case of regulator failure.

Comment: @Passerby A fuse makes sense, I will look into that. I think it would work better than the resistor. Thank you. :)